# Changing nLog logging level in Production

Tags: nlog

What's the best practice for changing the logging level for nLog in a production environment. The only way I can change it is to modify the NLog.config file, and then recycle the app pool. Is that how it should be done?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to change logging configuration, without restarting application, you should set autoReload="true".

**NLog.config file:**

```
<nlog autoReload="true">
   ...
</nlog>
```

More: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#wiki-automatic-reconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

NLog 4.6.7 allows you to change NLog LogLevel dynamically with minimum effort:

```xml
<nlog>
   <variable name="myLevel" value="Warn" />
    <rules>
      <logger minLevel="${var:myLevel}" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then you can have a Debug-button that changes the `myLevel`-variable (and maybe setup a Timer that restores the default value):

```cs
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myLevel"] = "Debug";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers(); // Explicit refresh of Layouts and updates active Logger-objects
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration